# Debugging does not works in files that are loaded in a Dialog box

Tags: visual-studio, office-js

I am using Visual Studio IDE. Debugging works fine in the html file and js files that are loaded in the task pane. But not in files that are loaded in Office Dialog box. From task pane, I am showing another html file in the dialog box. Please let me know what should I do?

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is a separate browser process from the task pane. In Visual Studio, you need to attach to the dialog process too in order to debug it.

Comment: It was working before and all of the sudden the debugging is not working in the files loaded in dialog box. I have not attached the dialog process before. How do we identify dialog process from the list of processes to attach? I see many processes related to edge and webview2 and tried attached them, but no success.

Comment: Try closing all browsers. Then debug the add-in again. There should be a lot fewer processes on the list. Attach to all of the edge and webview2 process.